# Merge only the changes associated with a particular branch in GIT?

Tags: git, version-control, merge, branch, git-merge

I am running into an issue when merging a particular branch into another branch.

We have a total of 3 branches we base our projects on. DEV, SUP, master. 
Developers base off their branch off of DEV and when the baseline their tickets I merge them in DEV for customer to test. There are no extra changes at this point because they based their local branch off of DEV.
The issue is when I attempt to MERGE for example branch DEV12345 into SUP, it shows a bunch of changes irrelevant to the changes done in DEV12345 branch(commit).

I have read about cherry-picking and some other solutions, but I am just starting out using GIT, so not really experienced enough to follow some of the answers I have seen.

I do not want to cherry-pick because it's my understanding when I MERGE SUP into master, I may lose the commits or have more merge-conflicts?

```
$ git merge DEV12345 --no-commit
$ git status
```

At this point it shows bunch of changes I don't want. 
I did try this which I got from another solution here in Stackoverflow.

```
$git add <fileNamePath> 
$git clean -f -d
$git reset HEAD
```

I think this is what I did. I have verified this did only bring in the specific change I wanted, which was that only 1 file from 100 files different. 
And I believe if I am not mistaken, since I did my own

```
$git commit -m "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

I would have lost the original author's commit/history, which it's not favorable for us.

Is there an easier way to doing this? That will also keep the history when I eventually post to master.
We post to SUP once customer approves a ticket, then once I have posted all approved tickets into SUP, I merge SUP into master, which is our Live system.

Can someone give put a solution in simple form so a starter can understand please?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Git allows you to squash commits into one (or more). It's based on the interactive `git rebase` application. Maybe, you can merge into SUP and then squash your commit together. Therefore, you keep the commits in your branch while having a meaningful merge into SUP.

For more information about `git rebase`, please check this [recipee](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html) or the git-book.

Bye